# A verb to describe traveling time and space

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

I've read it from a children's book and heard my friend used it to describe time and space traveling. It starts with trans- something. 
I've googled every possible synonym with it and can't find it. 
It's driving me crazy please help me.

Comment: I suppose asking that friend is out of the question? The term *transdimensional* is sometimes used for sci-fi space/time travel.

Comment: The fact that it came from a children's book is problematic. It might be a term created by the author that isn't in common use.